# Unity3d. WebGL. UI raycast targets don't get rotated when rotating html-container with css

Tags: css, unity-game-engine, webgl

I have stumbled upon strange behaviour on WebGL when rotating html-container with css. It works for everything, but raycast targets of ui elements. So all the elements look rotated, but their clickable areas are still at the starting positions with no rotation applied. I am curious if someone knows the reason and is there workaround? [How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaIpu.jpg)

Comment: No clue .. but very interesting use case! My guess would be: Unity still uses XY pixel space of your screen, not relative to the rotated canvas -> what is "wrong" is not the position of your objects but rather the interpreted position of the mouse cursor.

Comment: Id say report it as a bug to unity

Comment: @derHugo yep, sounds reasonable, can you point me where that interpretation occurs? Where to apply calculated correction?